# Interchanging of database servers

Tags: database, deployment

Hello I am still a newbie for database deployment.

Generally how are changes to a production database deployed for a release?

My client wants an entire new setup. We have 3 environments: DEV, INT, PROD. He want to make INT as PRODUCTION when QA has certified. This will be fine with application servers but as the state of database is very important, this is a problem for the database because we cannot make the INT database to be production unless we sync the production data to integration. But our database is of more than 300GB so it will take a lot of time to sync data and therefore a huge down time which is not advisible.

Can you guys please advise me in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The Most suitable way i know of to do such a synchronization before deployement consists on an offline integration using copies of the original data. At first it might seem as a heavy process, but it bears the advantages of keeping the original data available (problems might always happen during the sync) and alowing you to do all the necessary testing with the data before full deployement.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips for deploying to a production database:

1. Always have current backups of your production database. Just in case something goes wrong.
2. Make sure you use some kind of source control for your scripts. Just like code. Check in scripts, stored procedures, etc.
3. Always have rollback scripts for any *data* updates. For example, have a script that updates 100 records? Write a script that copies the data somewhere else temporarily and that can restore any changes you make. It's easy to test this in DEV and INT. Gives you a bit of peace of mind when making production changes to data.
4. Always have a recent backup for any *schema* changes. If you're adding a field to a table, see if you can copy the table to a temp table and then make your changes. Might not always be possible if the table is really large, but again, it lets you quickly rollback in case of an error.
5. Practice, practice, practice. Practice restoring backups of old production data. Practice running your scripts in DEV and INT. Be ready to re-deploy all stored procedures at any moment.

Another subject that can be tough that you touched on is having production data in INT. I would regularly restore production database backups to INT and DEV. It's well worth it for QA since it provides them with both the *quality* of production data and the *quantity*.

I would advise against turning the INT database into production however. Developers and QA will always put in garbage data for testing and you don't want to make that live.